# Image and Mesh in Same Plot in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, plot, mesh

This topic has been discussed but I've been unsuccessful.

I have a basic mesh plot in MATLAB displaying on x,y,z axis and I want to insert an image (jpg) on the floor, bottom of the grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to support @Dan's first suggestion (looking on the same thing while posted) with an example, here is how you can overlay or underlay an image on a surface using intensity values as surface grayscale:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(256); % surface
I = double(imread('cameraman.tif')); % image  

figure;
mesh(X, Y, Z, I); % overlay image as texture
colormap gray; hold on; 
c = 1.5*min(Z(:)); % scaling Z- location of image 
mesh(X, Y, c*ones(size(Z)), I) % underlay image as a constant-height surface
```

[image]

However `surf` with setting `'texturemap'` (linked answer, as he suggests) is a more slick approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've been at this so long.  Some reason when it is data visualization it is hard to find experts in this domain.

Comment: Since I just run into this again. For the record, you can also do the image overlay using `warp`, i.e. for the example above `warp(X, Y, Z, I./255)`

Answer (score 2):

If it is a grayscale image then perhaps you could display the image using `surf(X,Y,Z,C)` where X and Y will be the pixel coords and also corresponding to your floor at bottom of the grid (i.e. create them with `meshgrid`), Z will just be `zeros(n)` and C will be the pixel intensities. Then make your colour bar Grayscale. I'm not 100% sure I would assume you could use something like `hold on` to plot the surf and the mesh on the same figure.

After googling my above suggestion I found this: [How can I plot an image (.jpg) in MATLAB in both 2-D and 3-D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719502/how-can-i-plot-an-image-jpg-in-matlab-in-both-2-d-and-3-d). It looks like `SURF` is the way to go but instead of using the C parameter you can give it a texture map which can be an image. And also you only need to specify the X,Y,Z coords of the corners of the image which is nice.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am beginning to achieve the plot I've been at for a couple days.