# How to move an image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have written some code for a projectile motion. The user will enter the initial positions and speed and an angle of projection and Matlab will create the projectile motion.

```
while....

plot(x,y,'r','Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',6, 'LineWidth',2)
pause(0.1)
end....
```

It only shows that a point moves along the projectile direction. But I want to move a picture or image of a ball or a rocket or something else instead of a point or line so that it looks like the user is really throwing a  ball. I hope you can understand what i am trying to say.
Does anyone know how I can do this?
Thank you

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719502/how-can-i-plot-an-image-jpg-in-matlab-in-both-2-d-and-3-d)

Comment: Did you try 'hold on' right after the 'plot' command?